# Previewing resolution specific layout in Eclipse

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, layout

I've added a folder called `layout-976x600` in my android project for a resolution specific layout. All works fine, but I'm unable to preview the layout in Eclipse (4.2.1 Mac OS X Mountain Lion).

In the Graphical Layout tab, I just have a blank palette, viewing area, and the text "Loading editor" is forever displayed in the information box. Is it possible to get a preview here, or am I stuck doing work in the normal `layout` folder and moving once finished?

---

**EDIT:**
Ultimately this was fixed by renaming the folder. Oddly enough, if I renamed the folder, opened the file, renamed *back* and *finally* opened it again, it would sometimes work. Seems to be an issue with Eclipse. I should be using a legal identifier anyhow, so I marked that as the correct solution.

Comment: first, update your android tools to the latest version and eclipse adt plugin.
second, show us xml content )

Comment: Odd... when I copied the file to that other project, it opened just fine (with preview). I then tried deleting the original and moved the copied file back to the original location. Preview worked just after that.

Comment: I'm not surprized ) sometimes you need to restart eclipse to fix all unfixable problems )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

layout-976x600 is invalid name. There are only limited list of qualifiers you can apply to resource folders. This [page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) will help you.

Comment: That's curious... it works though :). I've tested on a regular device and on a tablet. The proper layout was used for each. I'm going to do a little bit more research before accepting this as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: If android finds unknown qualifier it ignores them. I checked my eclipse and it ignores them too and I can see preview. Maybe you should wait more time or by a new faster computer or you have some problems with android tools.... but still your qualifier is wrong )

Comment: Yeah, I just checked with a different project that had a similarly named layout directory, and it worked as it was supposed to. Hm... I'll need to dig some more and see what's different.

Comment: It seems to be related to the layout name, so I'll accept. If I rename to a valid identifier, they all work correctly.